# How to move from Excel to designing a Data Warehouse Model

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, modeling

I just started in Data Warehouse modeling and I need help for the modeling of a problem.

Let me tell you the facts: I work on flight data (aeronautical data),
so I have two Excel (fact) files, linked together, one file 'order' and the other 'services'.

- the 'order' file sets out a summary of each flight (orderId, departure date, arrival date, City of departure, City of arrival, total amount collected, etc.)
- the 'services' file lists the services provided by flight (orderId, service name, quantity, amount / qty, etc.)
  with a 1-n relationship (order-services) each order has n services

I already see some dimensions (Time, Location, etc ...). However, I would like to know how I could design my Data Warehouse, knowing that I have two fact files linked together by orderId.

I thought about it, and the star and snowflake schema do not work in my case (since I have two fact tables) and the galaxy schema requires to have dimensions in common, but I block it, is that I put the order table as a dimension and not as a fact table or I should rather put the services table as a dimension, but these are fact tables. I get a little confused.

How can I design my model?

Comment: Flight is your main fact table.  Service is also a fact table that supports Flight, although some people might want to query a service across flights.  Your dimension tables to support Flight should also support Service.

Comment: Ok, but how do i do to preserve the relation between the two tables ? Since every order (flight) has multiple services

Comment: Merge these two tables into one, keep order Ids and order information. If total amount can be computed by summing service amounts, then get rid of total amount field.

Comment: Good idea RADO, it seems that it will solve the problem, let me think about it

Answer (score 2):

First of all realize that in a *star schema* it is **not a problem to have more fact tables that are connected** - see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52085274/4808122).

So the first draw will simple follow your **two fact tables with the native provided dimensions**.

*Order* is in one context a *fact table*, in other context a *dimensional table* for the *service* table.

Dependent on your expected queries  you could find useful to **denormalize some dimensions** of the *order* table in the *service* table. So the service will have defined the departure date, arrival date etc. dimensions.

This will be done at the load time in the ETL job.

I will be somehow **careful to denormalize the  measures** from *order* to *service* - which will basically eliminate the whole *order* table.

There will be no problem with the measure *total amount collected* if this is a redundant sum  of the service amounts - you may safely get rid of it.

But you will need for sure the *number of flights* or *number of people transported* - those measure are better defined in the *order* fact table; you can not simple replicate them in the N rows for each *service*.

A *workaround* is possible, if you define a *main service* for each *order* and those measures are defined only in this row - in other rows the value is NULL. This could lead to unexpected results if queried naively, e.g. for number of flights per service.

**So basically I'd start with the two fact tables and denormalize some dimensions to the services if this would help to optimize the queries**.

Comment: Maybe I can't get the big picture. To sum up you telling me that in order to keep the link between the two 'tables' i have to denormalize just some dimensions ? not all of them ? I think this will not solve the problem because i would end up with two fact tables linked together... Isnt it better to merge all of them in one big 'service' fact table ?

Comment: @LougEagle the best way to proceed is if you post the schema of both tables and the expected queries. Basically I'm telling *denormalise all dimensions that will help you to optimize the queriesy* and *be carefull while denormalizing the measures*.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with one fact table of **Services**.  This fact would include all of the dimensions you might associate with the **Order** including a degenerated dimension of OrderId.

Once this fact is built out and some information products are consuming it, return to the **Order** and re-evaluate it to see if there are any reporting needs which are not being served, or questions which are difficult to answer with the **Services** fact.

Joining two facts together is always a bad idea.  Performance is terrible.  You are always better off bring the dimensions from, in your case, **Order** to **Services**.  Don't forget to include the context of the dimension in the column name and a corresponding role-playing dimension view for this context.  E.G. OrderArrivalCity, OrderDepartureDate, OrderDepartureTime.

You can also get yourself a copy of Ralph Kimball's [The Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/data-warehouse-dw-toolkit/)