# A table in my model records building valuations over time. Is it a slowly-changing dimension table or a fact fable?

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I'm building a data model for a report that allows users to analyze building valuations over time, and details about buildings and their current leases.

I have a fact table that contains leasing information, and a dimension table that contains building information.

I have a third table that measures building valuations recorded every other quarter. I want to know whether it should be considered a slowly-changing dimension table or as another fact table.

The structure of the tables is as follows.

**Fact_Leases**

| Lease ID | Building ID | Floor | Customer | Start Date | End Date | Occupied Area (sq ft) | Yearly Rent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 1 | Customer X | 1/1/2000 | 1/1/2020 | 60 | $10 |
| 102 | 1 | 2 | Customer X | 1/1/2010 | 31/12/2030 | 40 | $25 |
| 103 | 2 | 3 | Customer X | 6/1/2015 | 5/8/2032 | 15 | $17 |
| 104 | 2 | 1 | Customer Y | 5/6/2016 | 6/9/2028 | 5 | $12 |
| 105 | 3 | 1 | Customer Z | 4/3/2017 | 12/2/2020 | 50 | $19 |

**Dim_Buildings**

| Building ID | Building Name | Sq Ft | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Building 1 | 100 | 10 |
| 2 | Building 2 | 150 | 20 |
| 3 | Building 3 | 125 | 50 |

**?_Valuations**

| Building ID | Quarter | Valuation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q2 | $50 |
| 1 | Q4 | $55 |
| 2 | Q2 | $40 |
| 2 | Q4 | $35 |
| 3 | Q2 | $32 |
| 3 | Q4 | $44 |

At first, I thought the Valuations table was a dimension table because it relates to information about the building dimension. I considered joining the valuation data to the building dimension table but this would result in needlessly repeated rows, so I left it as a separate table.

However, the valuation table will not be used to filter the leases table, and the valuation column would be considered a measurement, which makes me think it is actually another fact table.

Can anybody clear this up for me?

Comment: If the valuation is a measure that is aggregated then it is a fact

Comment: Why do you think it is important to *classify* the table? There is [no strict border between dimensions and facts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52085274/4808122) in the Kimballs model. Call it either *Building-Quarter Dimension* or *Validation Fact*, though the latter is more realistic, as this will be a (very) quickly changing dimension if the validation moves each quarter...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes. It is a fact table.

You have two fact tables that differ only in terms of *granularity*. Your **Fact_Leases** table, for example, is a fact table at the granularity of a *lease*. I can assume this quite safely because it appears the Lease ID column is a primary key. Each row of that table represents a lease.

On the other hand, your **?_Valuations** table is a fact table at the granularity of *quarter-time-building*. That is, each row not only represents a building but also a quarter time period. And one way you can sort of know that this is a fact table is by understanding that if you had a date-dimension table, you could relate the two on their Quarter columns (although it would be a many-to-many relationship). Therefore, your date-DIMENSION table would be explaining the facts of your valuations. (I'd recommend, however, replacing your Quarter column with actual dates, and allow the date-dimension table to inform the quarters. That's an aside, though.)

Now, the problem of repeating valuation metrics occurs because you are trying to combine two fact tables at different levels of granularity. When you try to apply the valuations to the Fact_Leases table, which is at the granularity of lease, Power BI (or any BI tool, for that matter) can't understand how to apportion the valuation at the BUILDING level down to the LEASE level of granularity. So it just repeats. And it's important to keep this in mind when developing your reporting. No visualizations built at the context level of lease will be able to include a valuation metric because valuations exist only at a higher level of granularity.

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I appreciate your explanation.